# How to uncheck the CheckBox, when limit exceeds in android?

Tags: android

Hello I am New to Android, My requirement is allow the user to check maximum 3 number of checkboxes. when user is trying to check fourth one should populate dailogue.
Iam trying but the problem is fourth one is not unchecking...

can any one help me...

Regards 
Shiva.M

Comment: I doubt there is a bug in the "uncheck" code, so there might be one in your code. But we cannot help you if you don't provide that code ;D

Comment: have you tried to Disable the checkbox on the 4th?

Comment: ya i tried by checkbox.setChecked(false);

Answer (score 11):

Just uncheck the checkbox using the following code block:

```
     final CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkbox_id);
     if (checkBox.isChecked()) {
         checkBox.setChecked(false);
     }
```